# Dynamically Sorting Lists Alphabetically in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am having some difficulties with macros in Excel. I have a built a call logger in a workbook containing 2 macros:

- macro A moves all the data from worksheet A into worksheet B;
- macro B automatically sorts the data so one column is always in descending alphabetical order.

However, I can't get both macros to work at the same time. They both work individually but when I try to implement one macro into a workbook containing the other they seem to cancel each other out. Where am I going wrong? Is there a way of possibly combining the 2 macros, for example? Macros are below.

Macro A:

```
 Sub Macro6()
    ' Macro6 Macro
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
    Sheets("Logger").Select
    Range("B4:I4").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("DATA").Select
    Range("B4").Select
    lMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("B" & lMaxRows + 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets("Logger").Select
    Range("B4:I4").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
End Sub
```

Macro B:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H:H")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("H3").Sort Key1:=Range("H4"), _
          Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes, _
          OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
          Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
    End If
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for your assistance with this.

Comment: Macro A is one which you need to run explicitly whereas Macro B is one which runs automatically as it is triggered by a selection change event. Which sheet module contains the Macro B and in which order you want them to get executed?

Comment: If understand correctly what you want, you cannot do that! Excel macros do not run in parallel, but one after the other finishes. Neither when they are in different sheets, or workbooks of the same Excel instance.

Comment: @sktneer- Macro B Is contained solely within the workbook rather than a module, and macro A is contained within module 2. Macro A would need to be executed first, after which macro B should kick in and automatically sort the data.

Comment: @Blenikos- if this is not possible, would there be a way around this at all?

Comment: @JCarne, your code doesn't match your narrative: macro A is not moving _"moves all the data from worksheet A into worksheet B"_ while its just pasting the content of cells "B4:I4". Furthermore marco A is acting always on sheets "Logger" and "Data" while macro B (if in ThisWorkbook code pane) is (re)acting at any sheet selection change. You may want to clarify

Comment: @user3598756- sorry I should have clarified. Macro A is just effectively copying the data from B4:I4 on worksheet A, pasting it into worksheet B, then clearing the contents of those cells on worksheet A. The user data on worksheet A is solely held within those cells. The issue stems from the fact that Macro B will not react to any changes in worksheet B if macro A is also running.